# k8s gce1.8.7 - pods is forbidden - Unknown user system:serviceaccount:default:default

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-security, kubernetes-mongodb-sidecar

I have a mongo database in the gce . (config see below)

when i deploy it to a **1.7.12-gke.1**  everything works fine. Which means the sidecar resolves the pods and links then

now when i deploy the same konfiguration to **1.8.7-gke.1** resultes in missing permissions to list pods see below.

I don't get the point what has changed . I assume i need to assign specific permissions to the user account is that right ?

What am I missing?

**Error log**

```
message: 'pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list pods at the cluster scope: Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:default:default"',

mongo-sidecar | Feb 28, 2018, 11:04:19 AM | status: 'Failure',
mongo-sidecar | Feb 28, 2018, 11:04:19 AM | metadata: {},
mongo-sidecar | Feb 28, 2018, 11:04:19 AM | apiVersion: 'v1',
mongo-sidecar | Feb 28, 2018, 11:04:19 AM | { kind: 'Status',
mongo-sidecar | Feb 28, 2018, 11:04:19 AM | message:
mongo-sidecar | Feb 28, 2018, 11:04:19 AM | Error in workloop { [Error: [object Object]]
mongo-sidecar | Feb 28, 2018, 11:04:14 AM | statusCode: 403 }
mongo-sidecar | Feb 28, 2018, 11:04:14 AM | code: 403 },
mongo-sidecar | Feb 28, 2018, 11:04:14 AM | details: { kind: 'pods' },
mongo-sidecar | Feb 28, 2018, 11:04:14 AM | reason: 'Forbidden',
```

**Config**:

```
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fast
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:3.4.9
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rs0
            - "--smallfiles"
            - "--noprealloc"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
        - name: mongo-sidecar
          image: cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar
          env:
            - name: MONGO_SIDECAR_POD_LABELS
              value: "role=mongo,environment=test"
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongo-persistent-storage
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "fast"
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:

          storage: 5Gi
```

Comment: > Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:default:default"'  
  
The defauls service account should exist. Can you do " kubectl get serviceAccounts " and see that you have an account named "default" ?

Comment: Also run "kubectl get ns" to see if you have default namespace (which should ideally have default service account)

Comment: Use of RBAC is the default in 1.8.

Comment: right RBAC was the  trigger. in 1.7 the option for legacy auth is per default enabled and in 1.8 not. @JonahBenton if you make a post with a screen shot as solution i would mark it as solution. When i set the legacy auth option to enabled this is working. also worth noting upgrading a 1.7 cluster to 1.8 keeps the legacy auth enabled thats why another 1.8 cluster was working

Comment: Maybe you can add this information to the question or submit an answer to help anyone else that might have this issue in the future?

Comment: try to see if you can list the clusterrole, such as view, edit by using kubectl get clusterrole,  after that if you have correct clusterrole binding, it should work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to original solution: https://github.com/cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar/issues/75

You have to create role binding which will grant the default service account view permissions:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: default-view
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: default
```

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow because the link could break (for example, the GitHub project could be deleted or renamed). Please edit your answer to include a self-contained description of the solution.